# MySQL Import command does nothing

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

```
$ mysqldump -u user -p db < /home/user/Desktop/backup.sql


Enter password: 
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.1.41, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: dev
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.1.41-3ubuntu12.3

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2010-07-15 16:45:35
```

Out of the 61 MB sql file exported via PHPMyAdmin I show no tables in the dev database..... any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the command `mysqldump`, you should use the command `mysql`.  You can also `source /home/user/Desktop/backup.sql;` from within the `mysql` client interactively.

Answer (score 2):

Is it a typo here on site or are you using incorrect redirection?

It should be like this:

```
$ mysqldump -u user -p db > /home/user/Desktop/backup.sql
```

Comment: Webnet states in his original question, "I show no tables in the dev database"

Comment: I wonder then what 61Mb export does include?

Answer (score 1):

So the correct format is:

```
$ mysql -uuser -p db < /home/user/Desktop/backup.sql
```

Another shell method is to use the mysqlimport command

```
mysqlimport [options] db_name textfile1 [textfile2 ...]
```

So in your case

```
mysqlimport -uuser -ppassword --local db /home/userDesktop/backup.sql
```